# how to get the unique combination of columns and sort by them in python data frame?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe, group-by

how to get the unique combination of columns and sort by them in python data frame? I know I can use df.groupby(['col1','col2']).size() to get the unique combination. However, I also want to have the result order by the ascending order of col2, and then ascending order by col1. For example, if my dataframe is like this:

```
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    B     3
2    C     2
3    D     1
4    A     1
5    F     2
```

I would like the final output look like this:

```
  col1  col2 
0    A     1 
1    D     1 
2    C     2
3    F     2
4    B     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `col2` and `col1`, but then need [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) (if order columns `col1` and `col2` is important) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) - solution use default sorting in `groupby`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['col2','col1']).size().swaplevel(0,1).reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
  col1  col2  count
0    A     1      2
1    D     1      1
2    C     2      1
3    F     2      1
4    B     3      1
```

Second solution need first [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) in columns `col2` and `col1` and then add parameter `sort=False` to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), because by default `sort=True`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['col2','col1'])
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    A     1
4    A     1
3    D     1
2    C     2
5    F     2
1    B     3

print (df.groupby(['col1','col2'], sort=False).size())
col1  col2
A     1       2
D     1       1
C     2       1
F     2       1
B     3       1
dtype: int64
```

Another solution is first [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['col1','col2']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
  col1  col2  count
0    A     1      2
1    B     3      1
2    C     2      1
3    D     1      1
4    F     2      1

df1 = df1.sort_values(['col2','col1'])
print (df1)
  col1  col2  count
0    A     1      2
3    D     1      1
2    C     2      1
4    F     2      1
1    B     3      1
```